# Rails Deep Nested Form with Photos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have a deep nested form with offering having a gallery which has photos.

**offering.rb**

```
has_one :gallery, foreign_key: "offering_id",:inverse_of => :offering, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :gallery, allow_destroy: true
```

**gallery.rb**

```
belongs_to :offering, foreign_key: "offering_id",:inverse_of => :gallery
has_many :photos, foreign_key: :gallery_id, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :gallery
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['image_file_name'].blank? }
```

**photo.rb**

`belongs_to :gallery
has_attached_file :image, :styles=>{:photo => "600x400#"}`

**offerings_controller.rb**

```
def new
    @offering = Offering.new()
    gallery=@offering.build_gallery
    5.times{gallery.photos.build}
    @vendor=Vendor.find(params[:vendor_id])
end

def create
    @vendor=Vendor.find(params[:vendor_id])
    @offering=@vendor.offerings.create(offering_params)
    if @offering.save
        redirect_to vendor_path(params[:vendor_id])
    else
        gallery=@offering.build_gallery
        5.times{gallery.photos.build}
        render 'new'
    end
end

private
    def offering_params
        params.require(:offering).permit(gallery_attributes: [:id,:offering_id,{photos_attributes: [:id,:gallery_id,:image]}])
    end
```

**offerings/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for [@vendor,@offering],:html=>{:multipart => true} do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :gallery do |g| %>
        Pictures for Gallery
        <%= g.fields_for :photos do |p| %>
            <%= p.file_field(:image) %>
        <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>


Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"AApeyzQbi6TxYYKFG/alcea+rK9s/MP2o8X4vJS741o=", "offering"=>{"gallery_attributes"=>{"photos_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd2ea60aad0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150515-5596-nywang>, @original_filename="11261457_694846000643900_1047203131_n.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"offering[gallery_attributes][photos_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"11261457_694846000643900_1047203131_n.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "2"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd2ea60a8c8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150515-5596-1d988rp>, @original_filename="11271093_695669323894901_362202707_n.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"offering[gallery_attributes][photos_attributes][2][image]\"; filename=\"11271093_695669323894901_362202707_n.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}}}}, "commit"=>"Add your listing", "vendor_id"=>"10"}}
```

The problem is that although gallery is saving in the database, the photos are not inserting. It is not even attempting to insert via any query.

Comment: Hey I have the same logic in my rails 5 app. Can you tell me which was your real solution, please? Or any clue you could provide for me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['image_file_name'].blank? }` is expecting an attribute in the actual hash of params, as per your whitelist you only have `:id`, `:gallery_id`, or `:image` available. That reject would have to be one of those otherwise it'll never be found.

Answer (score 1):

The error was in

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['image_file_name'].blank? }
```

it had to be

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['image'].blank? }
```